# Date.now is not saving when $set document is executed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I have the following bit of code that updates my `latestComment`. When I `console.log` the updated document it has the date in it. However, if I go back into my MongoDB and check the field itself, it's not even there?

Here is the example output with just a text comment from the returned document

```
{ user: { userRecord: 5c9ba4d4347bb645e086527b },
  picture: null,
  video: null,
  document: null,
  text: 'Dwight Schrute',
  date: 2019-04-18T18:51:31.207Z }
```

**Code snippet**

```
CommentFeed.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.body.commentFeed },
        {
            $set: {
                latestComment: {
                    user: {
                        userRecord: req.user._id
                    },
                    text: req.body.text,
                    picture: req.body.picture,
                    video: req.body.video,
                    document: req.body.document
                }
            }
        },
        { new: true }
    )
        .then((feed) => {
            console.log(feed.latestComment); <----I get the date timestamp here
    ...
```

**Schema**

```
CommentFeedSchema = new Schema({
    latestComment: {
        user: {
            userRecord: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        },
        text: { type: String },
        picture: { url: { type: String }, blobName: { type: String } },
        video: { url: { type: String }, blobName: { type: String } },
        document: { url: { type: String }, blobName: { type: String } },
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now } <--Not saving
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am seeing that you are using `$set` to update your document(a record) in the DB. but `$set` is for updating the particular field in your document.

The default value works when is fire an insert query or so this won't work for you has you are updating the document and it will update only the fields which you have passed.

Note: Not to pass `null` value for Date